# 3D Unity game C# movement script falling issue

Tags: c#, 3d, game-physics

When i try to go down a slope my character keeps playing the falling animation everytime it takes a step, tried it on different steepness and happens everytime
This is the code i have now:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor.Rendering;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float maxSpeed;
    public float roSpeed;
    public float jumpforce;
    public float JumpGraceTime;
    [SerializeField] private float JumpHorizontalForce;
    [SerializeField] private Transform camTransfrom;

    [SerializeField] private GameObject headPos;
    [SerializeField] private bool crouch = false;
    [SerializeField] private bool canStand;

    private CharacterController characterController;
    private Animator animator;
    private float ySpeed;
    private float originalStepOffset;
    private float? lastGroundedTime;
    private float? JumpButtonPressTime;
    private bool isJumping;
    private bool isGrounded;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        originalStepOffset = characterController.stepOffset;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {   
        /* */
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 moveDirection = new Vector3(horizontalInput, 0, verticalInput);
        float inputMagnitude = Mathf.Clamp01(moveDirection.magnitude);

        if(!(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightShift)))
        {
            inputMagnitude /=  2; 
        }
        animator.SetFloat("Input Magnitude", inputMagnitude, 0.05f, Time.deltaTime);
        moveDirection = Quaternion.AngleAxis(camTransfrom.rotation.eulerAngles.y, Vector3.up) * moveDirection;
        moveDirection.Normalize();

        ySpeed += Physics.gravity.y * Time.deltaTime;

        if(characterController.isGrounded)
        {
            lastGroundedTime = Time.time;
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            JumpButtonPressTime = Time.time;
        }


        if (Time.time - lastGroundedTime <= JumpGraceTime)
        {
            characterController.stepOffset = originalStepOffset; 
            ySpeed = -0.5f;
            animator.SetBool("IsGrounded", true);
            isGrounded = true;
            animator.SetBool("IsJumping", false);
            isJumping = false;
            animator.SetBool("IsFalling", false);

            if (Time.time - JumpButtonPressTime <= JumpGraceTime)
            {
                ySpeed = jumpforce;
                animator.SetBool("IsJumping", true);
                isJumping = true;
                JumpButtonPressTime = null;
                lastGroundedTime = null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            
            characterController.stepOffset = 0;
            animator.SetBool("IsGrounded", false);
            isGrounded = false;

            if((isJumping && ySpeed < 0) || ySpeed < -2)
            {
                animator.SetBool("IsFalling", true);
            }
        }


        if (moveDirection != Vector3.zero)
        {
            animator.SetBool("IsMoving", true);
            Quaternion toRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(moveDirection, Vector3.up);

            transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, toRotation, roSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            animator.SetBool("IsMoving", false);
        }

        if(!isGrounded)
        {
            Vector3 velocity = moveDirection * inputMagnitude * JumpHorizontalForce;
            velocity.y = ySpeed;
            
            characterController.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        Crouching();
    }

    private void OnAnimatorMove()
    {
        if (isGrounded)
        {
            Vector3 velocity = animator.deltaPosition;
            velocity.y = ySpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            characterController.Move(velocity);
        }
    }

    private void OnApplicationFocus(bool focus)
    {
        if (focus)
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        }
        else
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        }
    }

    private void Crouching()
    {

        if(Physics.Raycast(headPos.transform.position, Vector3.up, 0.8f))
        {
            canStand = false;
        }
        else
        {
            canStand = true;
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftControl))
        {
            if (crouch == true && canStand == true)
            {
                crouch = false;
                animator.SetBool("Crouch", false);
                characterController.height = 2f;
                characterController.center = new Vector3(0f,1f,0f);
            }
            else
            {
                crouch = true;
                animator.SetBool("Crouch", true);
                characterController.height = 1f;
                characterController.center = new Vector3(0f, 0.55f, 0f);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to look through my code and check older posts on stackoverflow but haven't found anything that was like my problem